# Vector Find Error: no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits

Tags: c++, vector

myVector is a vector nodes. Each Node has an int value and a name that is a string pointer. I'm trying to make a simple function that will determine if any of the Nodes in this vector has this name.

```
vector<Node*>::iterator it; 
it = std::find(*(*myVector.begin())->name, *(*myVector.end())->name, found);
if (it != myvector.end()) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

When I run this, I get the error "no type named ‘iterator_category’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits". I'm guessing this has something to do with the setup of pointers, but I'm not sure what that would be or what this error means. Could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the the algorithm and `begin()`/`end()` member functions incorrectly. First of all,

```
*myVector.end()
```

is already undefined behavior, as all container `end()` functions return a one-past-the-end, i.e. not dereferencable iterator. Dereferencing it leads to UB.

Second, the `std::find` call should be

```
const auto it = std::find_if(myVector.cbegin(), myVector.cend(),
    [&found](const Node *n){ return n->name() == found; });
```

You need to specify a custom predicate - here, a lambda expression - because a `find` algorithm can only iterate over the nodes, not their names, and hence you must specify the way it determines a match by calling `Node::name()` and comparing it to `found`.

Let me add a couple of additional notes:

- To be able to pass the custom predicate, you need the `std::find_if` instead of `std::find` algorithm.
- I have used the `cbegin()` and `cend()` functions, as the container will not be modified.
- Using type deduction (the `auto`) for iterators is widely accepted and simplifies their usage.
- You might want to improve your naming. `it` could be `firstMatchingNode`, and `found` e.g. `lookupName`.
- If you are only interested in whether there is at least one matching node name, consider [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) with the same predicate. This is closer to your intent, as it discards the position of the match.